# Android: How to set drawablePadding programmatically?

Tags: android

Here is my code in xml layout:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mail_message_content_field"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/attachment"
    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
    android:gravity="center|left"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

The same way I want to change drawablePadding for drawable programmatically. How to do this?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You can get refernce of ur text view and then can set

```
UrTextView.setCompoundDrawablePadding(your padding value);
```

Comment: What if you have something like a dp value in your dimens that you want to use? I'm guessing you have to convert it to the usable value here?

Comment: @HuwDavies use `your_dp_value * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density`

Comment: The "correct" way would be to use `resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.padding)`

Answer (score 2):

```
textView.setCompoundDrwablePadding(takes_only_one_argument_for_all_side_padding);
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion , better was to set paading according to devices dimension is:

```
tvCompetType.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_svg_location), null, null, null);

tvCompetType.setCompoundDrawablePadding(getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.margin_xxsmall_4));
```